# PHP Date strtotime

Tags: php, date

I'm facing a problem with date formating and adding days.
I have a function like this:

```
public function test($date)
{
    var_dump($date);
    var_dump(date("d/m/Y", strtotime($date . '+ 1 days' )))

}
```

for this example if I use "02/09/2019" as date I get:

```
02/09/2019
10/02/2019
```

I'm expecting

```
02/09/2019
03/09/2019
```

Can someone help me find a solution to this problem?
Thanks

Comment: what did you expect? 02/10/2019 I guess? It's not fully clear what you think the problem is. Do you consider "02/09/2019" to be "2nd September" or "9th February"? That's the problem with ambiguous date formats, they're...well... ambiguous! So the computer may not interpret the string in the way you would, depending on your cultural norms. Better to use an unambiguous format such as YYYY-MM-DD for the input. You can still format the output in whatever style you prefer.

Comment: You passed in `m/d/Y` and then convert and display as `d/m/Y`.  Try `date("m/d/Y"`...

Comment: `Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed. If, however, the year is given in a two digit format and the separator is a dash (-), the date string is parsed as y-m-d.`

Comment: Save yourself a world of trouble and use the [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime) class to handle your date and time formatting, manipulation and conversion.

Comment: @ADyson i'm excpecting 03/09/2019

Comment: What is input date format?

Comment: Ok well, as per the quote from the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) which anyber posted, your string 02/09/2019 will be seen by the computer as meaning "9th Feb". So you can't expect to get 3rd September (or 9th March!!) as the result of adding one day to it. As per the advice on the next line, and already given here, you must either use a non-ambiguous format such as yyyy-mm-dd (e.g. 2019-09-02) as the $date string, or you can use DateTime::createFromFormat to create a date object straight from the format you're using now - you have to tell PHP what format it is

Comment: @DawidGałecki look at the input date 02/09/2019, and the stated expected output of adding one day to it (03/09/2019) and then it's pretty obvious what format the OP thinks it is. Of course, as we're discussing, that's not the format that PHP thinks it is.

Comment: Basically the 09 is been considered as day so its adding +1 to it so output is 10/02/2019.
The provided solution may not be perfect but it should server your purpose.
echo date("d/m/Y", strtotime(str_replace('/','-','02/09/2019') . '+1 days'));
which will give 03/09/2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The essential problem here is that PHP is interepreting `$date` as a different one to the date you intended it to represent. This is because you're using an ambiguous format for the date. Depending on your cultural norms, `02/09/2019` could mean `2nd September` (`d/m/Y` format - commonly used in Europe and other places) or `9th February` (`m/d/Y` format - commonly used in North America and other places).

PHP is treating your string as if it's an `m/d/Y` format, and adding one day to it - hence you get `10th February` as the result.

However, this shouldn't be too much of a surprise. What it will do with your string *is* documented and predictable. The [strtotime manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)  says, in the notes:

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at
>   the separator between the various components: if the separator is a
>   slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the
>   separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format
>   is assumed. If, however, the year is given in a two digit format and
>   the separator is a dash (-), the date string is parsed as y-m-d.
>
> To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD)
>   dates or DateTime::createFromFormat() when possible.

---

There are two basic ways to solve this, which I've demonstrated in the "test" and "test2" functions in the code sample below.

The first approach, in the "test" function keeps your existing code the same, but inputs the date in the universal `Y-m-d` format, so there's no confusion over which part is the day and which the month.

If that's not workable for you for some reason, then the second approach changes the code to use the [DateTime::createFromFormat](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) function, which will parse the date according to the format string you pass to it, and create a `DateTime` object which can then be manipulated and also re-formatted again (into any string format you choose) when you're ready to output it.

```
<?php
function test($date)
{
    var_dump($date);
    var_dump(date("d/m/Y", strtotime($date . '+ 1 days' )));

}

function test2($date)
{
    var_dump($date);
    $dt2 = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y", $date);
    $dt2->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
    var_dump($dt2->format("d/m/Y"));

}

test("2019-09-02");
test2("02/09/2019");
```

output of "test":

```
"2019-09-02"
"03/09/2019"
```

output of "test2":

```
"02/09/2019"
"03/09/2019"
```

Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/71e07798a109859cabd242d77acb1eafaef5bfe8

Answer (score 0):

Basically the 09 is been considered as day so its adding +1 to it so output is 10/02/2019.The provided solution may not be perfect but it should serve your purpose.

```
echo date("d/m/Y", strtotime(str_replace('/','-','02/09/2019') . '+1 days'));
```

which will give 03/09/2019

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/) a php **date-time library**. it makes working with dates very easy, it is very easy to format dates and add dates using this library. [Here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easier-datetime-in-laravel-and-php-with-carbon) is a quick tutorial

```
$dt = Carbon::create(2019, 09, 02, 0);
echo $dt->addDays(1);
```